# Organizing MQTT topics for large scale sensor network

Tags: mqtt

I am working on a project where multiple MQTT client devices are connected to the network and are managed from a single MQTT Master device.

Currently, the topology is as following:
[image]

From the image above, you can see that MQTT master is subscribed to cell/#.

Each MQTT sensor device is identified with unique ID. If sensor has been assigned ID = 1, then it is going to publish all information to /cell/1/#. For example:
Publish temperature data:

```
publish("/cell/1/temperature/",25)
```

Publishing speed data:

```
publish("/cell/1/speed/",80)
```

When a master device receive a message, it looks at the Identification number. For the example above, it parses the topic and sees that the message came from device with ID = 1. Once the master knows which ID the message has come from, it can do whatever it needs.

**My questions:**

**From the MQTT sensors side:**

Is it generally okay to have the devices publish to the same topics that the device has subscribed to even though the publisher does not really need to receive this information?

For example, each sensor device is also subscribed to a topic that corresponds to its ID. For instance:

```
subscribe("/cell/1/#");
```

I do this because sometimes the MQTT sensor devices needs to receive some commands from MQTT master device. For example the MQTT sensor might receive a ping command to which it must respond. The ping command is sent to topic:

```
 "/cell/1/ping/"
```

with a message "ping". Then the MQTT sensor responds to the same topic with a message "pong":

```
publish("/cell/1/ping/","pong").
```

Since the MQTT sensor is subscribed to all "/cell/1/#" topics, it will also receive a "pong" message but its irrelevant for the MQTT sensor.

**From the MQTT master side:**

Since MQTT master is subscribed to "/cell/#" to be able to receive all messages that come from different sensor devices. It will also receive the messages that MQTT master himself publishes. For example when MQTT master wants to ping MQTT sensor device with ID = 5, it will send the following topic and message:

```
publish("/cell/5/ping/","ping");
```

And since hes subscribed to everything above "/cell/#", he is also going to receive that message himself.

**To summarise everything up**

Is it generally better to split topics in seperate sections such as "write" and "read". To ensure that the MQTT device that sends the message does not receive the message himself if he doesnt need to.

For example I could have:

```
"/cell/1/request/ping/"
```

and

```
"/cell/1/response/ping/"
```

That way, the MQTT master would only be subscribed to `"/cell/1/response/ping/"` since he is the one waiting for the MQTT sensor response but he would publish to `"/cell/1/request/ping/"` topic. Since hes not subscribed to the topic himself, he wouldnt get the message.

And MQTT sensor device would be subscribed to `"/cell/1/request/ping/"` since he is the one that is waiting for the request and he would publish to `"/cell/1/response/ping/"`.

I hope my question is clear enough. Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: Please don't start your topics with a leading slash (and 100% definitely don't mix topics with/without them)

Comment: I fixed some typos in my post. All topics in my post should have a leading slash (I think the reason I used it there is because I thought it was going to be easier to parse all messages using regex by parsing all words in between 2 slashes.
Is there any reason why starting topics with leading slash is not good?

Comment: While legal in the spec, it's bad form and makes using advanced features like shared subscriptions harder. It really is better to not start topics with them, and rather than use regex, just split the string on the `/`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Yeah thats good idea to split using ```/```. I am not sure how I didint think about that!

Answer (score 0):

MQTTv5 allows you to pass a flag when subscribing that means the broker will not return messages to the client that published them if subscribed to a matching topic pattern.

This would solve your problem, but it depends on using a MQTTv5 broker and the client code supporting connecting with MQTTv5.

Otherwise I would suggest using different in/out topics so you don't have to self filter.

Comment: Understood. I will read up more about the flag that you are talking about. Otherwise, do you think that the example that I have given about the ```request``` and ```response```  ping message would be a decent start?